# Cannot seem to get JQuery to work in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to copy this panel/accordion interface:

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html

I thought it would be simple. I copied all the div tags to the index.cshtml and made reference to the respective jquery files in the _Layout.cshtml

Nothing works. When I move all the code to a simple html everything works.

Is there something I am not understanding about implementing this type of jquery interface in mvc3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to check what is the version that you're using with MVC3 and what's the needed for get this plugin to work..

Comment: I do not understand the importance of that? I copied all the respective js files from the sample and it did not work but then as an html it does.

Comment: the importance of that is because you're some plugins work with a specific version  (or greater) of jQuery.. where did you copy your scripts? how are you trying to include them? can you paste some code to try to help you?

Comment: Is it possible to share some code you have?

Comment: Are you testing locally, or deploying to a remote computer for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team is using jQuery and jQuery UI with MVC 3.  There's no real clever trick.  We're using Cassette, but the JavaScript files on the site are still accessible directly.  I.E. this would work:

```
<script src="/scripts/someDir/jquery.js"></script>
```

I assume you're getting a 404 on the script tag (you can check this in the Firebug net panel).  You probably just need to ensure jQuery and the plugins are installed and adjust the path to the script.

Comment: I am getting no errors, just a blank screen when it is part of a cshtml. Then when I move all the code to a html file in the mvc app it works.

Comment: @JoeGrasso, what does the network panel show?  There are other ways besides Firebug to check it, e.g. Chrome net panel, Fiddler, Wireshark, etc.

Comment: I downloaded Firebug and for some reason it said the js files could not be found, so I used @Url.Content. Now I am getting error readings like this: "Invalid selector: body > .ui-layout-west .pin-button". Does anyone have a clue what that is all about?

Comment: @JoeGrasso, that's a separate question, but it seems to be a [known issue](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-layout/browse_thread/thread/5eff5860172e5c3b/ed18afee83475a54?pli=1) people have hit with jQuery UI Layout.  Kevin Dalman said, "This could be because some other code or CSS is somehow overriding Layout's settings. Or perhaps the page structure is somehow altered."

Comment: @Mathew: So is there a solution with the known issue? I copied the code exactly from that site and removed everything that the pre-compiled layout had so I have no clue where to look.